# iptables script to update dyndns ip

Tags: networking, server, bash, scripts, iptables

So, I have a ubuntu 16.04 server which I want to secure with ddns iptables rules to certain ports. I did find a script and tried to alter it, because I coulnd´t get it to work. The script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
#allow a dyndns name

HOSTNAME=xxx.ddns.xxx
LOGFILE=/home/ddns/Logs/ddns.log
exec > /home/ddns/Logs/ddns_update.log 2>&1

Current_IP=$(host $HOSTNAME | cut -f4 -d' ')

if [ $LOGFILE = "" ] ; then
  echo $Current_IP > $LOGFILE
else

   Old_IP=$(cat $LOGFILE)

   if [ "$Current_IP" = "$Old_IP" ] ; then
     echo IP address has not changed
   else
    iptables -D INPUT -s $Old_IP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -D INPUT -s $Old_IP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -D INPUT -s $Old_IP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4000 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -D INPUT -s $Old_IP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4001 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -D INPUT -s $Old_IP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4003 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -D INPUT -s $Old_IP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4005 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -D INPUT -s $Old_IP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -D INPUT -s $Old_IP -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30300 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --src $Current_IP --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --src $Current_IP --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --src $Current_IP --dport 4000 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --src $Current_IP --dport 4001 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --src $Current_IP --dport 4003 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --src $Current_IP --dport 4005 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --src $Current_IP --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --src $Current_IP --dport 30300 -j ACCEPT
    echo $Current_IP > $LOGFILE
    echo iptables have been updated
   fi
fi
```

The problem is, that the the rules with the "old ip" are not getting deleted. All I get (in the log) is:

```
Bad rule (does a matching rule exist in that chain?).
```

I am a total newbie to ubuntu and scripting, therefore I think, I am overseeing the issue with the script.

Comment: Before you go much further you may want to note that 16.04 standard support ends in a month. Maybe use 18.04 or 20.04 When standard support ends no more help here or updates on the OS.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Will update it anyway, but somehow started with 16.04 since it was the initial system installed. However, I would like to know, where the failure comes from or what I am doing wrong with the script.

Comment: The error is self-explanatory - you're trying to delete a rule that doesn't exist or match.  You will need to run each command individually to find which rule is not matching properly.

Comment: I do understand the output. But when I list the iptables rules, I definately can see these rules and when I type them in with the associated ip address, they get deleted. But using the script, they won´t. The output give the error for every rule, that should be deleted.

Comment: This script is running as root, yes?  Do you save your `iptables` rules somewhere?  like `/etc/iptables/rules.v4` with `iptables-persistent` or something?  Asking because there may be an alternative way for you to do this that is going to be much simpler.

Comment: @ubuntunewbie I have a strong suggestion to reapproach your firewall handling in this case that will make rule handling **a lot simpler** for your script.

Comment: The script is running as root. The iptables rules are not persistent and being flushed with a script, that flashes them once after reboot, since if something happens like now, that rules are not being updated with actual ip, I still can login, after server reboot. Hence the rules are stored in sbin/

Comment: @ubuntunewbie I would suggest then that you use a different approach for your script and rules.  Only have a single INPUT rule.  That's the only rule you redefine with your script.  Put the remaining rules for port matches into a separate list - see my answer.  That means instead of adjusting 10 rules at once you're adjusting a single one.  Your script that flushes and reflashes them on reboot should be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I noticed is you're trying to edit a lot of rules in one go.  Let's make this a bit simpler.  Define the rules you *want* for 'ACCEPT' in a separate group of rules, but then only need one item added to INPUT

```
iptables -N DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED
iptables -A DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4001 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4002 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4003 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4005 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED -p tcp -m tcp --dport 30300 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED -j RETURN
```

This prepares the rules for what ports to *accept* in the alternative table called 'DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED'.

**Save your `iptables` rules so you have a base set of rules, AND you keep the `DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED` table into the foreseeable future.**

Now, this set of rules is not yet in line, and I am *intentionally* leaving off source IP at the moment.  Because we're going to handle it differently - in the INPUT table.

First, yank out all those independent port match rules you've got in the `INPUT` table.  We'll no longer need them with the `DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED` table.  Instead, you will have only *this single rule* in the `INPUT` table:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s IPADDRESS -j DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED
```

... this rule will say "If the source IP is the IP address we want to work with, then take the traffic and check it against the rules in `DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED` table.

Now, your script will simply do the following instead of handling a plethora of rules:

```
iptables -D INPUT -s OldIPAddress -j DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED
iptables -A INPUT -s NewIPAddress -j DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED
```

Just make sure that `DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED` remains in the environment with the rules I stated - that way you don't need to have individual rules to handle the Source IP data, and only need to define port match rules for the traffic in DYN_PORTS_PERMITTED.  Then, you only have to alter the IP address in a single INPUT rule.

I assume you have a default INPUT rule of `DROP` in this case, otherwise you have to finesse your rules.